# Vertical ScrollBar does not repaint using EnableScrollBar api

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapi, interop

I am trying to disable a VScrollBar control using the EnableScrollBar api. When I call the api it returns as if no problems ocurred but the VScrollBar is not repainted.

To reproduce the problem create a Vb.Net windows forms project, drop a VScrollBar control and a button to the form and paste the following code:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True)>
Public Shared Function EnableScrollBar(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nBar As Integer, ByVal value As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim wSBflags As UInteger = 3UI 'SB_VERT
    Dim wArrows As UInteger = 3UI 'ESB_DISABLE_BOTH
    Dim result As Boolean = EnableScrollBar(Me.VScrollBar1.Handle, wSBflags, wArrows)


End Sub
```

I tried using SendMessage to send a redraw (WM_REDRAW) and a paint (WM_PAINT) but cant get it to work. Any ideias?

Ps: If you drop a multiline textbox and use the same code it works....

Answer (score 1):

`SB_VERT` is for the vertical scrollbar as part of the non-client area of a window. For a scroll bar control, use the `SB_CTL` constant.